# Fetching application/dart script unsuopported

Tags: html, dart

I have my index.html file setup for a dart application like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>basic_app</title>
    <script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome has started throwing a warning at me that says:

Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details.

What do I have to change to get rid of this warning?
I believe it is caused by this line:

```
<script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome doesn't know about Dart, only Dartium can load Dart script tags. `pub build` doesn't remove the Dart script tag. There is the [dart_to_js_script_rewriter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter) transformer that removes that Dart script tag so that only the dart2js-transpiled JS code is loaded in production:

Add the package as `dev_`dependency`

```
dev_dependencies:
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
```

and the transformer configuration at **the end** of the transformers configuratino:

```
transformers:
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```